# Android app socket communication to Raspberry Pi server

Tags: java, android, c++, sockets, raspberry-pi

I've been trying to make

- a C++ SERVER on RPI that receives and shows strings sent from a Java app on android using socket communication.
- RPI serves as a SERVER using "udhcpd" and "hostapd"

problem: I execute the SERVER then the CLIENT. But the SERVER just shows nothing.

So can someone please help me? I would really appreciate it. THANK YOU!

**RPI SERVER (C++)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
socklen_t clilen;
char buffer[256];
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
int n;

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0)
{std::cout<<"ERROR opening socket"<<std::endl;
return 0;}

bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
portno = 5000;
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);


if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
{std::cout<<"ERROR ON BINDING"<<std::endl;
return 0;}

listen(sockfd,5);
clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

if (newsockfd < 0)
{std::cout<<"ERROR on accept"<<std::endl;
return 0;}

bzero(buffer,256);
n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
if (n < 0)
{std::cout<<"ERROR reading from socket"<<std::endl;;
return 0;}
std::cout<<"Here is the message"<<buffer<<std::endl;
return 0;
```

}

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
      try{
        Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.42.1",5000);
        String str = "abc";
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println(str);
        } 
     catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("Unknown host: kq6py");
        System.exit(1); } 
     catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("No I/O");
        System.exit(1);
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: Check your firewall settings. Probably net connections to the port are being blocked on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: add some errorhandling - maybe your data is never sent (e.g. permissions, not allowed to send data on main thread, etc.)

Comment: Where and when are you calling sendText()?

Comment: `RPI serves as a SERVER using "udhcpd" and "hostapd"` ????

Comment: @MartinTrummer Thank you. I added the error handling part (see edited code) but the RPI is still showing nothing

Comment: @greenapps Thank you the comment. My mistake, I just edited the code but it's still not working. The "udhcpd" and "hostapd" are Linux packages used for making the RPI a server and giving clients (the android) an IP.

Comment: There is no internet connection. Just the Android client connected to the RPI server via WIFI

Comment: why do you have a main method in your code - when you start the android app, this will never be executed, right? so: are you sure, that your code is executed at all (e.g. set a breakpoint, write a log-file)?
another thing I would try, is to make a small java-program first and execute it directly on your PC (instead of Android) and make this work.